# barplot graph is not working (beside = T)

Tags: r

I want to draw a graph of the mean by a value.

It's a statistic graph, and for this I made a list of each grade.

It used the "list" function to bring in each score and the average of each value using the "lapply" function.
But I tried to use it as a 'barlpot','beside =T' but the graph was not made properly.

I don't know if the graph format is wrong or what kind of mistake I made.

Code

```
list01 <-list(Sci=df_01$Sci,Eng = df_01$Eng,Math = df_01$Math)
C01_gd = lapply(list01,mean)

as.matrix(C01_gd)
barplot(as.matrix(C01_gd) ,border="white",beside = T)
```

Comment: replace `as.matrix(C01_gd)` with `unlist(C01_gd)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tentative solution (tentative, as you have not provided a sample of your data).

Some reproducible data for illustration:

```
set.seed(12)
df <- data.frame(
  Sci = sample(1:6, 100, replace = T),
  Eng = sample(1:6, 100, replace = T),
  Math = sample(1:6, 100, replace = T)
)
```

The calculation of the means could not be simpler using `apply`:

```
means <- apply(df, 2, mean)
```

And drawing the barplot is not rocket science either:

```
barplot(means)
```

[image]